# Spring data querying with complex object marked by @Param

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have an entity with aggregation information that I am going to receive from database:

```
class BookStats {
    String author
    String title
    Integer count
}
```

My question is could I use some complex object in Repository to filter statistic information. Something like that:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT new com.test.book.BookStats(b.author, b.title, count(b)) from Book b where b.title = :filter.title and b.author= :filter.author")
    List<BookStats> calculateBookStats (@Param("filter") Filter filter)
```

Comment: Did you check Projections https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks!  But my question is about filtering params

Comment: What you mean by **filtering params**, could you explain a bit?

Comment: @MehrajMalik I mean does `@Param("filter") Filter filter` could be a complex object, with fields

Answer (score 3):

Spring Data JPA allows to use SpEL :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.test.book.BookStats(b.author, b.title, count(b)) from Book b where b.title = :#{#filter.title} and b.author= :#{#filter.author}")
List<BookStats> calculateBookStats (@Param("filter") Filter filter)
```

More info [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions).